# DFS-R, delete database for replication group without impacting SYSVOL

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, dfs-r

I have one server, SRVA.  SRVA is a Domain Controller and has a SYSVOL type replication group (on the c drive) to SRV1 and SRV2, both also domain controllers.  This replication is working fine.

I have another replication group between SRVA (on the c drive) and SRVB and SRVC.  This is a normal replication group.  This replication is not working fine.  After a recent update, all of the replicated content began deleting from SRVB and SRVC at the request of SRVA.  I stopped the replication and re-seeded the directories.

I have tried to delete / rename / reconstruct the group, but the replication will not execute (error:4004 A tombstoned content set deletion has been scheduled).  So, I was going to delete the System Volume Information\DFSR directory, but I can't determine the impact that will have on the SYSVOL replication.

Is my SYSVOL replication stored in the same place my normal replication because they're on the same volume?  And, will deleting the DFSR directory do damage to the other domain controllers?

All servers involved are either Windows Server 2012 or 2012 R2.

Comment: :( Once you get this fixed, stop using your domain controllers for anything other than domain controllers.